# How can I change HTML code of an <asp:Panel> on Server side at PostBack?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

Suppose I "generate" this HTML elements on a .cs, at `Page_Load()` :

```
foreach (Object obj in Objects)
{
    Literal boxStart = new Literal();
    boxStart.Text = "<div class=\"option-box\">";   

    Literal boxEnd = new Literal();
    boxEnd.Text = "</div";          

    HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
    hf.Value = "0";
    hf.ID = "category" + obj.ID;

    panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(boxStart);
    panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(hf);
    panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(boxEnd);
}
```

after, on client side, some "hf.Value"s will change (thanks to some JS functions). Than, on PostBack :

```
protected void cmdCerca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (HiddenField hf in panelCategorieGuida.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>())
    {

    }
}
```

I want to change the class `option-box` (on the main div for each HiddenField) to `option-box-selected` where hf.Value is "1".

How can I do it? Of course avoiding Javascript functions/controls on postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating `div` as a server-side control, instead of literal. This tag can be created with [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx):

```
foreach (Object obj in Objects)
{
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes["class"] = "option-box";

    HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
    hf.Value = "0";
    hf.ID = "category" + obj.ID;

    div.Controls.Add(hf);
    panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Add(div);
}
```

Now each hidden field is nested directly in server-side control representing `div` which can be accessed via simple `Parent` property:

```
protected void cmdCerca_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (HtmlGenericControl div in panelCategorieGuida.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>())
    {
        HiddenField hf = div.Controls.OfType<HtmlGenericControl>()[0]; //leaving out all the exceptions handling
        if (String.Equals(hf.Value, "1"))
        {
            div.Attributes["class"] = "option-box-selected";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, the problem now is : seems that panelCategorieGuida.Controls.OfType<HiddenField>() count is 0? I can't enter to the foreach...

Comment: Response.Write(panelCategorieGuida.Controls.Count) count the number of div's parent. Seems I can't  browse internal Control? Damn... :(

Comment: `FindControl` works only in a single level of control hierarchy, totally forgot about that. Please see the updated post. And as for `String.Equals` - this is the correct way of comparing strings in .NET.

Comment: 1) on an IEnumerable I can't access with [0], but ok, I use LastOrDefault();

Comment: 2) for what I know, == call .Equals, so what's differences? I feel better (on reading code) using ==, honestly :)

Answer (score 0):

boxStart.Attributes["class"] = "someClass" <= this is how you can change class atribute in code behind

Comment: Uhm, I thought to it, but I need to access to it from each hiddenField... can't do `hf.Parent().Attributes["class"] = "someClass"`